# Finding the values of a matrix multiplied between two unknown matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, unitary-matrices, inverse-problems

This is a slightly vague question I think, but I am wondering if there is any elegant way of solving this problem.

Say I have a multiplication between three unitary matrices operating on a vector, stacked as such

$\hat{s}_{out}=\mathbf{A_0} \mathbf{M} \mathbf{A_N} \hat{s}$

All matrices are 3x3 rotation matrices and I want to find out as much as possible as I can about matrix **M**. I can know, or measure directly, the product $\mathbf{A_0}\mathbf{A_N}$, and the vector $\hat{s}$ can also be any vector I choose (and I can do multiple measurements with different $\hat{s}$)

What can I determine about the matrix **M** with the information I have available?

Comment: It is important for the answer to your question for you to say whether you (a) know only the product $A_0A_n$ or (b) know each of $A_0$ and $A_N$ separately. Please make this clear.

Comment: I can only know the product $\mathbf{A_0}\mathbf{A_N}$. I will edit the post to add this information more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By plugging in a basis of vectors for $\hat s$, we can get the matrix $X = A_0 M A_N$, and there is no further information to be attained by plugging in values for $\hat s$.

We can then use $A_0A_N$ as follows. Note that
$$
X = A_0MA_N = A_0 A_N [A_N^{-1}MA_N] \implies\\
A_N^{-1}MA_N = (A_0A_N)^{-1}X.
$$
That is, we are able to obtain a matrix unitarily similar to $M$. This allows us to compute the eigenvalues of $M$ (equivalently, its angle of rotation).

As Robert's post below demonstrates, this is all we can know about $M$.

Comment: good approach (+1)

Answer (score 1):

To just add slightly to what Ben Grossman wrote: once you know a matrix unitarily similar to $M$, you can't know any more from the information given.  Indeed if $T = U M U^{-1}$ where $U$ is unitary, $A_0 M A_N = (A_0 U^{-1}) T (U A_N)$, and $A_0 U^{-1}$ and $U A_N$ are unitary with the same product $A_0 A_N$.